# Why is my keyboard not working after moving to an SSD?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I just cloned my Windows 7 hard drive to a new SSD.

The system will boot from it, and when it does the USB mouse works, but the USB keyboard does not. It's plugged into a USB 2.0 port, and it does work fine to invoke the BIOS setup, but not once Windows starts. The keyboard works fine if I boot from the old hard drive.

Any ideas?

Comment: How long did you let it sit to allow Windows to (re)detect the keyboard?  It can take a minute or more the first time (sometimes).  Have you tried moving KB to another USB port?

Comment: Quite some time. My userid requires a password, and I can't enter it. And yes, I tried the keyboard on several different ports.

Answer (score 0):

if you have ps2 mouse OR/And keyboard, we can fix it.

**solution a:**

plug that ps2 mouse and/or keyboard.  they will most likely work.

then  device management >

```
+ universal serial bus
  + usb related entry1
  + usb related entry2
  + ....
```

on each entry right click > delete

when popup open   **Check  "Delete its software"**, press remove. (otherwise, wont work)

after this done  plug usb keyboard mouse they will work.

success!!!

---

in my case i ran   "sfc /scannow" .  when the progress at %55 .  i did the **step by step solution**

but running sfc /scannow may not be necessary.